Covariance of increasing function of positively correlated random variables
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two non-negative random variables such that $\text{Cov}(X,Y)\geq0$. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ be a non-decreasing function. Is it true that $\text{Cov}(g(X),Y)\geq0$, and if not, what are the minimal assumptions (either on $g$, or the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, or both) such that this is true?

Let's try $\mathbb P(X=0, Y=0) = \mathbb P(X=1/2,Y=1) = \mathbb P(X=1,Y=0) = 1/3$.  Thus $$\text{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb E[XY] - \mathbb E[X] \;\mathbb E[Y] = \frac{1}{6} - \left(\frac12\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) = 0$$  Take $g(0) = 0$, $g(1) = 1$ and $0 < g(1/2) < 1$.  Then $$\text{Cov}(g(X),Y) = \frac{g(1/2)}{3} - \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{g(1/2)}{3}\right) \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) = \frac{2 g(1/2) - 1}{9}$$
which can be positive, negative or $0$.

Thank you this is helpful! I think it is definitely possible to come up with counter examples (as the one you showed above). Since this is motivated by economic application, where X and Y are some "nice" continuous variables, and g could be made "nice" if necessary, I'm just wondering what assumptions are necessary for the statement to be true.

You might look up the FKG inequality.
